# AWS S3 - Python script to get number of columns in a file

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3

AWS S3 - Python script to get number of columns  in  each row of a file

I need to get the number of columns from each row of a file residing in AWS S3 bucket with | as delimiter then print whether all rows has same number of columns

**Input File**

```
100|name1|Test
200|name2|Test45
300|name3
400|name4|Test1|subject
```

**Result**

In this case the number of columns based on | is 2,2,1,3 for each row respectively.

The number of columns are differing.

Comment: It would help here to simplify your question.  You are asking several things at once: (1) get file from AWS bucket; (2) count columns in a row; (3) compare number of columns.  It seems likely you already know how to do some of these steps.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment on your question, you are asking several questions at once.  Here I will answer the simple python portion:

`"Given a table as list of strings and a delimiter, how can I determine if they have the same number of rows?"`.

Doing this is relatively straightforward - since you don't know how many columns you expect you will need to calibrate off the first row, and validate other rows against it.

```
def columns_are_consistent(rows, delimiter):
    """
    Returns True if the number of delimiters is the same in every row,
    and False otherwise.
    Note that in general:  # columns  ==  # delimiters + 1
    """
    if not rows:  # This could also be "if len(rows) < 2"
        return True  # Can't be inconsistent if there is nothing
    # Calibrate on first row
    expected = rows[0].count(delimiter)
    # Validate remaining rows, note that "all([]) == True"
    return all(row.count(delimiter) == expected for row in rows[1:])
```

Comment: I am new to python . I'm able to understand the logic used but please can you explain if it  is sufficient just to call the function with  (filename,|) as arguments  for ( rows,delimiter) ? or is it like I need to open the file before processing it?

Comment: @Rajeev, if you had a file with contents like `Input File` in your current question, then you could do logic like this:
`print columns_are_consistent(open(filename).readlines(), '|')`.  Though I would recommend not trying to fit it in one line